# wrapping text in only 2 rows and adding '...' after

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have some text of various lenght but my textBlock is limited as in width and height.

How can i restrict the text (for a given width and height) to only 2 rows and add some '...' to the textBlock so that the user knows that the all text didn't fit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this.

```
<TextBlock 
    Text="This is a fairly long string and should display as two lines ending with an ellipsis to denote it doesn't all fit in the control" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
    Height="70" />
```

Note that the number of lines is limited only by setting the height of the textblock (in this case to 70, but it will depend upon the font size.  Setting `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` is what controls how the string is cut off at the end, and `TextWrapping="Wrap"` ensures that you can see the second line.

Obviously you can bind the Text value to whatever you like as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Worked great!